# runtime of 2 dependent nested for loops

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

```
for (i=1; i<=n ;i=i*2){

  for (j=1; j<=i ;j++){

  basic_step;

  }
}
```

Regarding the above nested loops, I can't seem to understand why is the following runtime analysis is correct (specifically the **first equality**), when $k$ is defined as $\log i$, meaning $i=2^k$. 
What is the process that one should come up with, in order to decide this setting and the sigmas' indices? While I do understand that the outer loop runs for $\Theta(\log n)$ times, I still can't grasp the setting of $k$. A clarification will be very much appreciated!

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\log n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^k}1$$

Answer (score 2):

The value of $i$ at the $k$'th iteration (starting from zero) is $i_k := 2^k$. The inner loop runs $i_k$ times, for a total of $i_0 + i_1 + \cdots + i_K$, where $K$ is the largest number such that $i_K \leq n$, that is $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$. Therefore the running time is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^k = 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor + 1} - 1 = \Theta(n).
$$